# #REACT - GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/scripts/app.js/ net::ERR_ABORTED

Tags: reactjs, console

I just started my adventure with react and at the early beginning i have this error in my console. Everything seems to be fine, but the error is still there.
Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: What is your webpack config, where is the bundled file created. how are you importing it in your app

Comment: damn i uploaded wrong picture.  now is correct., there is no webpack yet just two files thats it. i instaled live-server thru npm and nothing more

Answer (score 0):

The GET query is not being fulfilled. Check app.js is in correct with respect to localhost.

Comment: can you please tel me how to do that?

Comment: can you upload it somewhere? i will fix it for you :)

Comment: the app.js is empty. there is no code at all. in the index.html as you can see not much either.

Comment: I opened the file in the Firefox browser, and Firefox console says that the „file:///scripts/app.js” couldn't be loaded.
After that i removed the "/" at the beginning of the script source. 

'<script src="scripts/app.js"></script> instead of <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>

and in the Firefox and Opera browser it all works well but it doesn't in Google Chrome.

Comment: cd to the folder>>
npm install then 
npm start